# How to call a method from another component after view is fully loaded?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using MatMenu from Angular Material inside my 'Header Component'. I just need to open the Menu under certain conditions. However this method only works inside ngAfterViewInit(), after the view is loaded.

```js
export class HeaderComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('triggerCart') trigger: MatMenuTrigger;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.openMenu();
  }

  openMenu() {
    this.trigger.openMenu();
  }
}
```

```html
<button mat-button 
        [matMenuTriggerFor]="shoppingCartMenu" 
        #triggerCart="matMenuTrigger" 
        (menuOpened)="isOpened($event)" 
        (mouseenter)="largeScreen ? triggerCart.openMenu() : ''">
</button>
```

I need to call this method from another component, but the Menu trigger is undefined outside ngAfterViewInit.

```html
<button mat-stroked-button
        (click)="someMethod()">
</button>
```

```js
export class ProductDetailComponent {
  @ViewChild(HeaderComponent) header: HeaderComponent;
  
  someMethod() {
    this.header.openMenu();
  }
}
```

How can I achieve a comunication between my components after my Header Component is loaded?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can query select a template reference that also has an assignment. `#triggerCart="matMenuTrigger"` might not match `@ViewChild('triggerCard')`. I am saying I'm not sure, but what if you add another `#something` to the same element and try to query that instead.

Comment: `#triggerCart="matMenuTrigger"` actually matches `@ViewChild('triggerCard')` and works inside my component. But only inside `ngAfterViewInit()` method.

Comment: that means that `someMethod()` is called before the header component has finished attaching the view. When is `someMethod()` being called?

Comment: I have a `(click)` event inside `ProductDetailComponent` view. The 'Menu' inside `HeaderComponent` needs to be triggered by this click from `ProductDetailComponent`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a way to do it (but not necessarily the best way). It's to give an idea of the interactions between components.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d8tbav?file=app%2Fproduct%2Fproduct.component.ts)

Product component

```
export class ProductComponent {
  clickBehavior = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  click() {
    this.clickBehavior.next(1);
  }
}
```

Product markup

```
<my-header [openMenu]="clickBehavior"></my-header>
<div>
  <button (click)="click()">Click</button>
</div>
```

Header component

```
export class HeaderComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('trigger') trigger: MatMenuTrigger;
  @Input() openMenu: Observable<any>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.openMenu.subscribe(value => {
      if (value) {
        this.trigger.openMenu();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Header markup

```
<button mat-button
        [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"
        #trigger="matMenuTrigger">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

The idea is to trigger an Input of the Header component and this is done using a BehaviorSubject in the Product component.

Reference:

- https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular
- https://thinkster.io/tutorials/learn-rxjs-observables/using-behaviorsubject-for-values-that-change-over-time

Comment: Is it possible do achieve the same result in this structure?                     
  `app.component.ts
 
    <app-header [openMenu]="clickBehavior"></app-header>

  <!-- ProductDetailComponent belongs here -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Comment: @James I would make that a separate question.

Comment: there you go: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51770417/how-to-call-a-method-from-another-component-after-view-is-fully-loaded-appcompo)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a shared service and injecting the service where it is required.

Setup a shared service, i put methods to get, set and toggle the menu state.

NOTE: in order to animate this because it uses ngIf you will need to use angular animations.

SharedService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable()
    export class SharedService {

    //The current menu state
    private showMenu_ = false;

    //get the current menu state
    get showMenu() {
        return showMenu_;
    }

    //set the menu state
    set showMenu(state: boolean) {
        this.showMenu_ = state;
    }

    //toggle the menu
    public toggleMenu() {
        this.showMenu_ = !this.showMenu;
    }


}
```

Inject the service into appComponent so we can control the menu state with it.

appComponent.ts

```
import { SharedService } from 'PATH TO SHARED SERVICE';

...

constructor(public sharedService: SharedService){}
```

Set my-header to show/hide based on the state set in the sharedService.

appComponent.html

```
<my-header *ngIf="sharedService.showMenu"></my-header>
```

Inject the service into any other component/page to change the state of the menu.
In this case ProductComponent.ts.

ProductComponent.ts

```
import { SharedService } from 'PATH TO SHARED SERVICE';

...

constructor(public sharedService: SharedService){}
```

ProductComponent.html

```
<div>
  <button (click)="sharedService.toggleMenu()">Click</button>
</div>
```

**Or with BehavourSubject from service.**

Create the BehaviorSubject in SharedService.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

//The current menu state
private showMenu_ = false;
private showMenu$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new 
BehaviorSubject(false);

//get a reference to showMenu$ for subscription
public menuState() {
    return showMenu$;
}

//Change menu state to show.
public showMenu(){
    this.showMenu_ = true;
    this.showMenu$.next(this.showMenu_);
}

//Change menu state to hide.
public hideMenu(){
    this.showMenu_ = false;
    this.showMenu$.next(this.showMenu_);
}

//Toggle menu state.
public toggleMenu(){
    this.showMenu_ = !this.showMenu;
    this.ShowMenu$.next(this.showMenu_);
}

//get the current menu state.
public getMenuState() {
    return this.showMenu$.getValue();
}
```

Inject the service into appComponent so we can subscribe to the menu state.

appComponent.ts

```
import { SharedService } from 'PATH TO SHARED SERVICE';

...

export class appComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

//variable used to show/hide the menu.
public showMenu;

//reference to subscription so we can unsubscribe later.
private this.menuStateSub: Subscription;

constructor(public sharedService: SharedService){}

ngOnInit() {  
    //subscribe to the menuState BehaviorSubject
    this.menuStateSub = this.sharedService.menuState().subscribe((state)=>{
        this.showMenu = state;
    })
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    //unsubscribe before leaving the page
    this.menuStateSub.unsubscribe();
}
```

Set my-header to show/hide based on the state set in the sharedService.

appComponent.html

```
<my-header *ngIf="sharedService.showMenu"></my-header>
```

Finally inject the service where we need to control the menu state.

ProductComponent.ts

```
import { SharedService } from 'PATH TO SHARED SERVICE';

...

constructor(public sharedService: SharedService){}
```

and now we can use the service to toggle the state.
ProductComponent.html

```
<div>
  <button (click)="sharedService.toggleMenu()">Click</button>
</div>
```