# How to call a method from another component after view is fully loaded (AppComponent)?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using MatMenu from Angular Material inside `HeaderComponent`. I just need to open the Menu under certain conditions (method), calling this method on `ProductDetailComponent`. However this method only works inside `ngAfterViewInit()`, after the view is loaded.

I found a way to comunicate from `ProductDetailComponent` to `HeaderComponent`, however there is a Children-Parent relationship to reach the components. `HeaderComponent` is called from `AppComponent`.

Here is AppComponent

```html
<my-header [openMenu]="clickBehavior"></my-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet> <!-- ProductComponent -->
```

ProductComponent

```js
<router-outlet></router-outlet> <!-- ProductDetailComponent -->
```

ProductDetail component

```js
export class ProductComponent {
  clickBehavior = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  click() {
    this.clickBehavior.next(1);
  }
}
```

ProductDetail markup

```js
<!-- i need to move it to app component 
<my-header [openMenu]="clickBehavior"></my-header>
-->
<div>
  <button (click)="click()">Click</button>
</div>
```

Header component

```js
export class HeaderComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('trigger') trigger: MatMenuTrigger;
  @Input() openMenu: Observable<any>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.openMenu.subscribe(value => {
      if (value) {
        this.trigger.openMenu();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Header markup

```js
<button mat-button
        [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"
        #trigger="matMenuTrigger">Menu
</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Comment: can you add your code in stackblitz.com

Comment: i would like to achieve this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d8tbav-aprwho), but using this structure on AppComponent `<my-header [openMenu]="clickBehavior"></my-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a shared service and injecting the service where it is required.

Setup a shared service, i put methods to get, set and toggle the menu state.

SharedService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable()
    export class SharedService {

    //The current menu state
    private showMenu_ = false;

    //get the current menu state
    get showMenu() {
        return showMenu_;
    }

    //set the menu state
    set showMenu(state: boolean) {
        this.showMenu_ = state;
    }

    //toggle the menu
    public toggleMenu() {
        this.showMenu_ = !this.showMenu;
    }


}
```

Inject the service into appComponent so we can control the menu state with it.

appComponent.ts

```
import { SharedService } from 'PATH TO SHARED SERVICE';

...

constructor(public sharedService: SharedService){}
```

Set my-header to show/hide based on the state set in the sharedService.

appComponent.html

```
<my-header *ngIf="sharedService.showMenu"></my-header>
```

Inject the service into any other component/page to change the state of the menu.
In this case ProductComponent.ts.

ProductComponent.ts

```
import { SharedService } from 'PATH TO SHARED SERVICE';

...

constructor(public sharedService: SharedService){}
```

ProductComponent.html

```
<div>
  <button (click)="sharedService.toggleMenu()">Click</button>
</div>
```

**Or with BehavourSubject from service.**

Create the BehaviorSubject in SharedService.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

//The current menu state
private showMenu_ = false;
private showMenu$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new 
BehaviorSubject(false);

//get a reference to showMenu$ for subscription
public menuState() {
    return showMenu$;
}

//Change menu state to show.
public showMenu(){
    this.showMenu_ = true;
    this.showMenu$.next(this.showMenu_);
}

//Change menu state to hide.
public hideMenu(){
    this.showMenu_ = false;
    this.showMenu$.next(this.showMenu_);
}

//Toggle menu state.
public toggleMenu(){
    this.showMenu_ = !this.showMenu;
    this.ShowMenu$.next(this.showMenu_);
}

//get the current menu state.
public getMenuState() {
    return this.showMenu$.getValue();
}
```

Inject the service into appComponent so we can subscribe to the menu state.

appComponent.ts

```
import { SharedService } from 'PATH TO SHARED SERVICE';

...

export class appComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

//variable used to show/hide the menu.
public showMenu;

//reference to subscription so we can unsubscribe later.
private this.menuStateSub: Subscription;

constructor(public sharedService: SharedService){}

ngOnInit() {  
    //subscribe to the menuState BehaviorSubject
    this.menuStateSub = this.sharedService.menuState().subscribe((state)=>{
        this.showMenu = state;
    })
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    //unsubscribe before leaving the page
    this.menuStateSub.unsubscribe();
}
```

Set my-header to show/hide based on the state set in the sharedService.

appComponent.html

```
<my-header *ngIf="sharedService.showMenu"></my-header>
```

Finally inject the service where we need to control the menu state.

ProductComponent.ts

```
import { SharedService } from 'PATH TO SHARED SERVICE';

...

constructor(public sharedService: SharedService){}
```

and now we can use the service to toggle the state.
ProductComponent.html

```
<div>
  <button (click)="sharedService.toggleMenu()">Click</button>
</div>
```